# Java BouncyCastle :der length more than 4 bytes

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle, jce, pkcs#12

I'm trying to load a pkcs store using BouncyCastle provider. I'm getting the p12 file using the classloader like this -

```
InputStream p12 = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("pkcsfile.p12");
```

and then use the inputstream to load it into my keystore like this -

```
        KeyStore ks = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", provider);
    ks.load(p12,"password".toCharArray());
```

The load method throws an exception -

> java.io.IOException: DER length more than 4 bytes

It does work fine when I five it a FileInputStream. I'm not sure what's going on. Can someone help? - thanks

Comment: My bad. I was using maven to build my code and it was filtering the p12 file and inserting stuff in it.